# Again Tex Live 2020 installation failed on windows 10

Tags: texlive-2020

I have tried Installing TeX Live 2020 on my Windows 10 operating system, all the packages (4032) have been installed, but at end of installation i got installation has failed[image: Screen Shot of Error Message], Please help me out in this problem,

Thank you!

[image: 2nd time installation error]

This time **i have disabled antivirus, windows defender and firewall**, but still at the end got this error, you can see all (4035) has been downloaded. and got installation failed message at the end.

How can i fix this, i ran 'exe' file as administrator.

please help me out.....

Comment: Give the log file (in the code tags), not as a screenshot, so that its content can be seen and copied.

Comment: Try if you can call pdflatex. If it works you can install the missing packages later.

Comment: I would take a wild guess and say that you have installed an package, that was just in process of updating. Thats why it is "broken." Test, if you can compile some (any) documents and report if it is working or not ...

Comment: Hello AndreC, i am not able to find any log file as it is empty.

Comment: Hey Ulrike Fischer, how can i call pdflatex ?

Comment: Hello Tomas Krulis, there is no any application related to TeX Live, so i am not able to run anything

Comment: To call pdflatex, open a command line window and type `pdflatex --version` and then press the ENTER button.

Comment: @RAUSHANRaj The log file you put as a screenshot, did you delete it?

Comment: Just try again, but go to advanced mode and pick a smaller scheme, e.g. basic. You can always install missing pieces, or even the full scheme later. And if you are the only user, then there are no advantages in installing as administrator. The access denied in the first screenshot is puzzling, the failure in the second looks indeed like a package was being updated on the server, as Tomáš Kruliš suggested.

Comment: Thank you all for your important suggestions, 

@Siep i have installed smaller scheme i takes 681mb of size and installation completed,......
But i am not able to use TeX Live and not able to open editor for writting anything.

Comment: Is there any editor i have to install explicitly to use Tex Live ??

Comment: You can install texworks via TeX Live Manager. [link](http://www.tug.org/interest.html) lists various third-party editors.

Comment: Thank you Guyss, i have installed TeX Live full version of 7211mb size, in my friend Windows 10 system, by deactivating Firewall and Defender while installation, these both are cause of that error........... Thank you once again, it is working completely fine.